# Efficient algorithm, for cleaning large csv files

Tags: python-3.x, csv

So I've got a large database, contained inside csv files, there about 1000+ of them with about 24 million rows per csv. And I want to clean it up.

This is a example of data in the csv:

[image]

So as you can see there are rows that have the same 'cik' so I want to clean all of them so we get unique 'cik' and we do not have any duplicates.

I've tried to do it with python, but couldn't manage to do it.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Are you looking to reset the `cik` field so that it is unique, or are you looking to filter out duplicates of the `cik` field, so there is only one entry per `cik` value?

Comment: @PaulProgrammer I want to clean the duplicates, so there many rows that have the same ip and cik, so I want to clean them

Comment: @PaulProgrammer So here at the picture you can see that some cik as 1136894 repeat so there are 2 rows with that cik and they both have the same cik so I need to remove rows like that

Comment: How do you choose which one to keep?

Comment: @Marichyasana Well the end output should contain the unique cik, with unique ip

Comment: Some rows have the same IP and the same cik but different values (e.g. size, accession).  It should be trivial to filter out ip/cik dups, but you still have to chose which other values to keep.

Comment: Other columns are not that important, just want to check for the ip and cik

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what I used to filter out all the duplicates with the same 'cik' and 'ip'

```
import pandas as pd

chunksize = 10 ** 5
for chunk in pd.read_csv('log20170628.csv', chunksize=chunksize):
    df = pd.DataFrame(chunk)
    df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["cik", "ip"])
    df[['ip','date','cik']].to_csv('cleanedlog20170628.csv', mode='a')
```

But when running the program I got this warning:

```
sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (14) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.`
```

So I am not sure does my code have a bug, or it something to do with the data from the csv.

I opened the csv to check that data its seems alright.

I have cut the number of rows from 24 million to about 5 million that was the goal from the start. But this error is bugging me...

Comment: This approach will miss duplicates that occur in different chunks. That may not matter depending on the application, but it is a characteristic of processing the data in chunks.

Answer (score 0):

The [tsv-uniq](https://ebay.github.io/tsv-utils/docs/tool_reference/tsv-uniq.html) tool from [eBay's TSV Utilities](https://github.com/eBay/tsv-utils) can do this type of duplicate removal (disclaimer: I'm the author). `tsv-uniq` is similar to the Unix `uniq` program, with two advantages: Data does not need to be sorted and individual fields can be used as the key. The following commands would be used to remove duplicates on the `cik` and `cik` plus `ip` fields:

```
$ # Dedup on cik field (field 5)
$ tsv-uniq -H -f 5 file.tsv > newfile.tsv

$ # Dedup on both cik and ip fields (fields 1 and 5)
$ tsv-uniq -H -f 1,5 file.tsv > newfile.tsv
```

The `-H` option preserves the header. The above forms use TAB as the field delimiter. To use comma or another character use the `-d|--delimiter` option as follows:

```
$ tsv-uniq -H -d , -f 5 file.csv > newfile.csv
```

`tsv-uniq` does not support CSV-escape syntax, but it doesn't look like your dataset needs escapes. If your dataset does use escapes, it can likely be converted to TSV format (without escapes) using the `csv2tsv` tool in the same package. The tools run on Unix and MacOS, there are prebuilt binaries the [Releases](https://github.com/eBay/tsv-utils/releases) page.